# Download file using httprequest in C# Code

Tags: c#, api

I am try to download pdf file from below code using webRequest in C# Code.I have tried below code but no error and no output is showing.Please check this below code and advise how to do this...

**Note:**

1. PlayResponeAsync method is not executing When I debug
2. I am using .Net framework 4.0

```cs
private static void DownloadCurrent() {
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://einvoicing
        .internal.cleartax.co/v2/eInvoice/download?
        irns=11eaf48a909dda520db27ff35804d4b42df2c3b6285afee8df586cc4dbd10541");
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    webRequest.Headers.Add("owner_id", "78c6beda-54a2-11ea-b064-0af3f8b02c24");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("gstin", "29AAFCD5862R000");
    webRequest.Timeout = 3000;
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(PlayResponeAsync), webRequest);
}

private static void PlayResponeAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
    long total = 0;
    long received = 0;
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;

    try {
        using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = 
            (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("[file name to write]");
            using (Stream input = webResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
                total = input.Length;

                int size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (size > 0) {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                    received += size;

                    size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }

            fileStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you use Postman?

Comment: yes, its working fine in postmen

Comment: It's hanging for me in postman just like it's hanging in this code. The request goes out, then sits on "sending"... then after a while it returns `504 Gateway Time-out`. The server is having issues, not your code.

Comment: Why are you using almost 10 year old deprecated stuff like .NET 4.0 and WebRequest, especially since the documentation of WebRequest specifically states not to use it anymore and instead use HttpClient?

Comment: hanging problem is solved,it works fine in postmen but still not working in above code